# Sugestões de Ferramentas apache para desenvolver em php com Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Bom pessoal, estou querendo desenvolver em php, e pra isso é preciso instalar uma ferramenta que faça meu pc virar metade servidor, como todo mundo sabe existem várias ferramentas dessas para baixar, como: XAMP, WAMP, EASYPHP etc.
Só que todas essas dão suporte ao SGBD MYSQL.

Queria saber se existem ferramentas desse tipo, mas que venham por padrão com suporte ao SGBD POSTGRESQL para me indicarem. (É um projeto para faculdade, professor exigiu usar O SGBD POSTGRESQL).

OBS:
Eu encontrei uma ferramenta da Bitnami chamada WAPP STACK, só que não gostei, quando atualizo o arquivo php, ele demora pra atualizar no navegador.

Comment: Não entendi o problema, basta instalar o postgres e habilidar o driver no php. Se precisar de um programa para manipular a base de dados pode usar o pgAdmin que já vem com instação do postgres.

Comment: como habilita esse drive no php ?

Comment: Está usando windows ou linux?

Comment: sim, uso Windows 10

Comment: Está familiarizado com o pgAdmin?

Comment: já usei ele algumas vezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois drivers para fazer conexão com o postgres o pgsql que permite usar as função [pg_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php) e o [driver para PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php). A instação é feita da seguinte maneira abra o php.ini e procure as linhas:

```
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Descomente (remova o ponto e vírgula) de ambas. Reinice o apache, para testar se foram instaladas corretamente crie um arquivo php com apenas:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
```

Isso vai mostrar todas as configuraçõe do php.

Se tiver o php configurado na linha de comando pode fazer

```
php -m
```

Comment: ok. resolveu o meu problema, obrigado