# Comunicar PHP com PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou tentando comunicar um programa feito em php com o bd postgreSQL.
Fiz uma classe conexao, conforme demonstra abaixo:

```
<?php
class conexao{

var $connect;
var $con_string = "host=localhost/TCC port=5432 dbname=TCC user=postgres  password=123456";


function conexao(){
$this->connect = pg_connect($this->con_string);
}

function executarSQL($sql){
return pg_query($this->connect, $sql);
}

function prepararString($texto){
return '\''.$texto.'\'';
}


}
?>
```

e Essa é a classe do index.php:

```
<?php
//session_start();
include ("classes/conexao.php");
$postgresql=new conexao;


if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
$usuario=$postgresql->converte($_POST['usuario']);
$senha=$postgresql->converte($_POST['senha']);
$sql= 'select * from usuario where usuario='.$postgresql-
>prepararString($usuario).' and senha='.$postgresql->prepararString($senha);

$result = $postgresql->executarSQL($sql);        
if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
    header("Location: anexos/principal.php");
}else{
    echo "<center><font align='center' size='5' color='RED'>O NOME DE USUÁRIO E SENHA DIGITADOS SÃO INCORRETOS.</a></font></center><br>";


 }
}
else{
header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Eu coloquei todo o código dentro da pasta do xampp, htdocs, e consigo visualizar o site, porém, na hora de fazer a comunicação com o bd, ele consta esse erro:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso\SISTEMA DO TCC\src\classes\conexao.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso\SISTEMA DO TCC\src\index.php(41): conexao->conexao() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso\SISTEMA DO TCC\src\classes\conexao.php on line 9

Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema??? Obrigada!

Comment: Verifique no seu `php.ini` se você instalou/ativou a extensão do `postgresql`

Comment: Precisa instalar o driver do postgres tentou [esse procedimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172657/91)?

Comment: Oi pessoal, deu certo! Fiz as alterações no arquivo php.ini e imediatamente  começou a comunicação. Obrigada!